# How to pass objects through parameters of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass objects through a function that finds words between two other words.

I'm trying to pass:

- sentences.para1.cat - **to** - findStringBetween(**parameter1**,― , ―)
- sentences.para2 - **to** - findStringBetween(―, **parameter2**, ―)
- sentences.para3 - **to** - findStringBetween(―, ―, **parameter3**)

---

the console should log:

- love all the
- hate
- never had a

---

```js
sentences = {
  para1: [
    cat: [
      "I love all the cats",
      "I hate cats",
      "You never had a cat before"
    ],
    dog: [
      "We can get a dog"
    ]
  ],
  para2: [
    "I",
    "You",
    "We"
  ],
  para2: [
    "cat",
    "dog"
  ]
}

function findStringBetween(str, first, last) {
  var r = new RegExp(first + "(.*)" + last)
  ab = str.match(r)
  result = ab[1].trim()
  console.log(result)
}


findStringBetween(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3);
//parameter1 should pass all of sentences.para1.cat
//parameter2 should pass all of sentences.para2
//parameter3 should pass all of sentences.para3
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is no JSON in the code, so it's a bit hard to answer

Comment: use `JSON.stringify()` b4 pass?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the question… I don't know all the terms to coding language.

Comment: are you saying that how to convert the array into json and send as parameter?

Comment: No… sorry… I'm just trying to pass it as it is… I though it was called a JSON… but I just found out it's not

Comment: I think you can simply pass `sentences.para1.cat` to your function and since `sentences.para1.cat` is an array, it may have multiple items, you can loop inside your function and access each item.

Comment: Is the `sentences` dynamic? Will its structure change? What's the requirement here?

Comment: `para1` appears to be defined incorrectly. You have used square brackets which defines an array however you have attempted to assign th eobject property `cat` which is not going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findStringBetween method accepts a single a string and you would like to use it for multiple string. You have two options:

1. Use your method inside a loop invoking it for every member of cat.

   ```
   for(let i=0; i< cat.length(); i++)
       Use cat[i]
   ```
2. You can refactor your method to accept an array instead of string. In this case you should use the loop inside your method.